# How to fadeout with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I made a pretty basic slider that shows some records of a database. I used `fadeinout` to make a fading effect. But somehow I can't fix a delayed fadeout. Now the div fades in and immediately fades out without a delayed `fadeOut`. So how can i make sure that the `div` fades in and after a couple of seconds the same `div` fades out?

Here is the code I use (first the .css and then the .php):

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} //Laat hem loopen
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; //Laat zien als blok (blokkeert display="none")
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000); //Tijd instellingen (iedere 1000 = 1 seconde)
 

}
```

```css
.mySlides {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 1s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 1s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','dbusername','dbpassword');
 
 if (!$con)
 {
  echo 'Geen verbinding met server';
 }
 
 if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'eventqy179_postwall'))
 {
  echo 'Database niet geselecteerd';
 }
 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM postwall
   ORDER BY id DESC";
 $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
 if(!$query)
 {
  echo 'Onbekende fout gevonden';
 }
 
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
  
  echo '<div class="mySlides">'.$row['bericht'].'</div>';
  
 }
?>
```

Comment: define your fadeInOut animation in another css class like 'myFadeInOut', then in the function=carousel, remove/add it in dom.classList.

Comment: How do you mean?